# .mockStatic is undefined for the type Mockito

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-code, mockito

I am attempting to run all of my unit test cases in VS Code. When I run `./gradlew clean build`, it completes successfully. However when I attempt to use VS Code's testing UI, several of my test files fail because "The method mockStatic(Class<AwsCredentialsManager>) is undefined for the type Mockito". I am pretty sure it's not an issue with the code, because I haven't changed anything from my company's original working repo, and also the gradle is building successfully. Do I need to download anything from Mockito in order for it to work?